# Do our belly buttons consist of scar tissue?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, human-physiology

I read an interesting post on Facebook the other day saying that we all have a visible scar since birth - our belly button. This got me thinking (and research for me only found results regarding belly button piercing) is the belly button made up of scar tissue?

I seem to recall that there are some stem cells still within the umbilical cord (which is why doctors tell you to spend the money to have it saved (I think)) so I was wondering if scar tissue closed the hole left by our cut umbilical cord, or if the stem cells divided to produce normal skin tissue.

Comment: According to Wikipedia they are scar tissue.

Comment: @canadianeradianer I'd like something more definitive than Wikipedia that can be changed by anyone (like when the lunar eclipse said that the moon would blow up)

Comment: I think the question hinges on the definition of scar tissue and the histology of the navel tissue. Given that the navel is not a functional organ, other than as a locus for piercings, I think finding a conclusive scientific answer is next to impossible.

Comment: @SolarLunix I'm sure you are, which is why I didn't post an answer. Just thought you might like to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The place where the cord was cut do not stay with us - [it falls in a week](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/imagepages/9055.htm) +- after the birth, while the umbilicus is the only visible natural scar formed by natural processes, not by gynecologists:

[image]

Multiple sources say the umbilicus has a scar tissue in it.

> After birth the umbilicus is the only naturally formed visible scar on
>   the body.

Br J Plast Surg. 1998 Oct;51(7):538-41. Umbilicosculpture: a concept revisited.

> Umbilicus [is a scar](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21404518), which is the place of the previous merger of the
>   fetus with the umbilical cord.